# The C++ way to relocate object of implicitly non-movable class

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor, move-semantics, mutable

I'm writing some custom library like stl, but without allocations in ctors and with disabled copy ctors in resource owning classes (because the environment doesn't support exceptions and all allocs on the heap needs to be checked by retcode).

So I'm porting btree from https://github.com/Kronuz/cpp-btree/, and got stuck because of problem of code in conjunction with my approach.

*value_type*, as in all stl implementations, is *std::pair<**const** Key, Value>*. **const** qualifier makes the whole pair implicitly non-movable.

So code

```
x->construct_value(j, std::move(fields_.values[i]));
```

(https://github.com/Kronuz/cpp-btree/blob/35ac0ec96f1fca1463765f169390059ab82d3aac/btree/btree.h#L615)

in fact doesn't move object (returns T& instead of T&&) and

```
new (v) value_type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

(https://github.com/Kronuz/cpp-btree/blob/35ac0ec96f1fca1463765f169390059ab82d3aac/btree/btree.h#L883)

is rightly unable to construct pair by copy ctor.

Is there a way to relocate object in memory without or bypassing copy-move semantic? Of course, the simple workaround is to make *std::pair<**Key**, Value>* with mutable key, but it's not exactly the same.

I found "trivially_realocable" proposal by Arthur O'Dwyer, and I made conclusion that it's exactly about the case.
(https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/18/announcing-trivially-relocatable/)

Comment: Obviously, no.  You either respect the language's semantics for copy/move, or you go outside the language.  You could solve it in the standard computer science way:  Add a layer of indirection.  1) Have the container keys be _pointers_ to your real keys.  2) Change your resource holding class to be a _handle_ (i.e., opaque pointer) to instances holding the _actual_ restricted resource.  (Actually, those two are the same, just in case #2 you give a name to the handle and not just use naked pointers.)

Answer (score 4):

Arthur O'Dwyer here! :)

Indeed, there's no way to do what you want in standard C++. In fact, there's no way to do what you want in [P1144 trivial-relocation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1144r5.html)–land, either. Essentially, you've got a type like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/T1dfaa):

```
using Trouble = std::pair<const std::unique_ptr<int>, int>;
```

which is not copyable (because `unique_ptr` is not copyable) but also not movable (because `const unique_ptr` is not move-from-able).

The operation you want to perform on it is called "relocation." [You have named it `move_value`](https://github.com/Kronuz/cpp-btree/blob/35ac0ec96f1fca1463765f169390059ab82d3aac/btree/btree.h#L615), but you should go right now and rename it to `relocate_value` so that the reader of your code knows that you don't mean "move" in the C++ sense; you mean "relocate"!

In P1144-land, "relocate" is literally a synonym for "move and then destroy the source." So P1144 considers your type `Trouble` to be non-relocatable, because it is non-movable. P1144 doesn't try to introduce a *new* verb "relocate"; it simply provides a performant codepath for types that are *already* relocatable under the current standard when the operation happens to be trivial. It's impossible to make a type that is P1144-trivially-relocatable without also being movable-and-destructible, in the same way as it's impossible today to make a type that the compiler will recognize as "trivially copyable" without its also being copy-assignable. The existence of the individual component operations is a *prerequisite* for the triviality trait. (I hope that helps explain why P1144 does it that way!)

---

To reiterate: You can't solve your problem without going outside of the standard.

So, how would I design a solution to your problem?

Step one, I'd write the client code the best way I knew how:

```
// Relocate value i in this node to value j in node x.
void relocate_value(int i, btree_node* x, int j) {
    assert(x != this || i != j);
    assert(0 <= i && i <= fields_.count);
    assert(0 <= j && j <= x->fields_.count);
    if constexpr (my::is_trivially_relocatable_v<value_type>) {
        memcpy(&x->fields_.values[j], &fields_.values[i], sizeof(value_type));
    } else {
        ::new (&x->fields_.values[j]) value_type(std::move(fields_.values[i]));
        fields_.values[i].~value_type();
    }
}
```

Notice that I've inlined the `x->construct_value` and `destroy_value` stuff here. In real life I might factor this stuff back out into a helper. P1144 names this helper `std::relocate_at`:

```
// Relocate value i in this node to value j in node x.
void relocate_value(int i, btree_node* x, int j) {
    assert(x != this || i != j);
    assert(0 <= i && i <= fields_.count);
    assert(0 <= j && j <= x->fields_.count);
    my::relocate_at(&fields_.values[i], &x->fields_.values[j]);
}
```

Okay, that's the client's side of the situation. Now what do we do on the warrantor's side? In P1144-land, the compiler takes care of figuring out which types are trivially relocatable. But (A) we don't have P1144's compiler support, and (B) we actually want a slightly different definition anyway, because we want `const unique_ptr` to be considered trivially relocatable. So we'll make up a customization point that type-authors can customize:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_trivially_relocatable : std::is_trivially_copyable<T> {};
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_trivially_relocatable_v = is_trivially_relocatable<T>::value;
```

Notice the extra parameter for ["This one weird trick for customization by template (partial) specialization"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/04/26/std-hash-should-take-another-template-parameter/) (of the class template, *not* of the variable template). This lets us write customizations like

```
template<class A, class B, class = std::enable_if_t<my::is_trivially_relocatable_v<std::remove_const_t<A>> && my::is_trivially_relocatable_v<std::remove_const_t<B>>>>
struct is_trivially_relocatable<std::pair<A, B>> : std::true_type {};
```

---

The practical engineering concern here is: Whose responsibility is it to define the specialization(s) of `my::is_trivially_relocatable` for standard library types such as `std::pair` etc.? If both you and your coworker define specializations for the same type, you have an ill-formed program.

Furthermore, professional coders have proven *very bad* at guessing whether complicated STL types such as `std::string` and `std::list` are trivially relocatable in practice. So giving you and your coworker this power is really asking for subtle bugs all over the place. (See [Folly issue 889](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/889), for example.)

Finally, if both you and your coworker *forget* to add a specialization for your trivially relocatable type `Widget` (where `Widget` happens to be movable and destructible as well), then your code will silently lack this optimization — which is definitely a downside for a lot of people. If we're going to permit this optimization, we ought to make sure that it happens *automatically*, and doesn't get pessimized just because someone misspelled a template specialization.

---

TLDR:

- You called the operation `move_value` but you should call it `relocate_value`.
- P1144 would not help your actual use-case with `const unique_ptr`; it optimizes only types which are already movable in C++20, and `const unique_ptr` is *not* movable.
- You can simulate P1144 with a customization point. You'll be in good company (Facebook Folly, Bloomberg BSL, EASTL), but there are huge maintainability downsides to consider.

Comment: "*in the same way as it's impossible today to make a type that the compiler will recognize as "trivially copyable" without its also being copy-assignable*" Um... you actually can do that. For some reason, the trivial copyability rules only require that *at least one* of the copy/move constructors/assignment operators is trivial; the others can be deleted and the type will still be trivially copyable.